# Alpha Vantage client too slow

Tags: php, rest, finance, alpha-vantage

I have this very simple PHP call to Alpha Vantage API to fill a table (or  list) with NASDAQ stock prices:

```
<?php
function get_price($commodity = "")
{

  $url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=' . $commodity . '&outputsize=full&apikey=myKey';
  $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
  $date = $obj['Meta Data']['3. Last Refreshed'];
  $result = $obj['Time Series (Daily)']['2018-03-23']['4. close'];
  $rd_result = round($result, 2);
  echo $result;
}

?>
<?php get_price("XOM");
  get_price("AAPL");
  get_price("MSFT");
  get_price("CVX");
  get_price("CAT");
  get_price("BA");
?>
```

And it works, but just so freaking slow. It can take ove 30 secs. to load while the json file from Alpha Vantage loads in  a fraction of second.

Does anyone knows where am I going wrong?

Comment: When I tried accessing those URL's, it takes me about 2-4 sec to completely fetch them (each). When trying your code, it took be about 16-18 sec to execute it all, which is correct since you're fetching 6 URL's. If their API is lagging slightly (or your server do, since you're fetching a lot of data at the same time), it could take longer sometimes.

Comment: Yes, but definitely there has to be other way to make the process faster (ie. making all calls at simultaneusly, not in a row), because imagine I want to get a simple list of all 100 companies in NASDAQ, which is something quite reasonable, it would take several minutes minutes to fetch them all...

Comment: There are PHP libraries for making asynchronous HTTP requests. You  can search for some and try them out and see if they work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This what i did when the API took time to reply, my solution is written in C# but the logic would be the same.

```
    string[] AlphaVantageApiKey = { "RK*********", "B2***********", 4FD*********QN", "7S3Z*********FRX", "U************I3" };
    int ApiKeyValue = 0;
    foreach (var stock in listOfStocks)
    {
        DataTable dtResult = DataRetrival.GetIntradayStockFeedForSelectedStockAs(stock.Symbol.Trim().ToUpper(), ApiKeyValue);
        ApiKeyValue = (ApiKeyValue == 4) ? 0 : ApiKeyValue + 1;
    }
```

I use 5 to 6 different API keys, when i'm querying data. I loop thought each of them for each call. There by reducing load on one perpendicular token.

I observed that this improved my performance a lot. It takes me less than 1 min to get Intraday data for 50 stocks.

Another, way you can improve your performance is to use

> outputsize=compact

compact returns only the latest 100 data points in the time series.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: [Batch Stock Quotes](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/#batchquotes)**

*You might want to consider using this type of query as well. Multiple stock quotes all in one call.*

Also, using the full output size is grabbing data from the past 20 years, if applicable. Take that out of your query and have the API use its condensed output default.

---

**EDIT**: According to the above, you should make changes to your query. But it can also be an issue with your **server**. I tested this for a use case I am working on and it takes me a few seconds to get the data, albeit I am only pulling it for one stock symbol on a page at a time.

Try increasing your memory limit if things are too slow for your liking.

```
<?php
  ini_set('memory_limit','500M'); // or your desired limit
?>
```

Also, if you have shared hosting, that *might* be the problem. However, I do not know enough about your server to answer that fully.

Comment: link doesn't say anything about "batch quotes"... 